# Google OAuth2 with Passport and Express

Tags: express, oauth, google-oauth

I am struggling with getting Google OAuth to work with my Express/React application whilst using Passport.js. I am using JWTs, not sessions.

In my React webapp client, I have a "login with Google" button that calls my backend API `/auth/google/` with the following route setup in Express:

`router.get('auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {session: false, scope: ['email','profile']}) );`

My Passport.js `google` strategy is:

```
 const googleStrategy = new GoogleStrategy(
    {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/google/callback",
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    async (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        try {
            console.log('profile', profile);//              ** CORRECT USER PRINTED ** 
            let existingUser = await User.findOne({ 'google.id': profile.id });
            // if user exists return the user 
            if (existingUser) {
                console.log('Found existing user...');
                return done(null, existingUser);
            }

        // if user does not exist create a new user 
        const newUser = new User({
            method: 'google',
            googleId: profile.id,
            profileImage: profile.photos[0].value,
            firstName: profile.name.givenName,
            lastName: profile.name.familyName,
            shortName: profile.displayName,  
        });
        await newUser.save();
        return done(null, newUser);
        } catch (error) {
            return done(error, false)
        }
    }
);
```

My Google developer dashboard is setup to call the following URL in my Express API backend upon successful authentication: `/auth/google/callback`

My Express route for this is defined as: `router.get('auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {session: false}), authController.googleAuthCallback);`

My Express `googleAuthCallback` function is defined as:

```
exports.googleAuthCallback = async (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.user) // ** WRONG USER PRINTED HERE ** different from above user printed in google strategy
}
```

The strange this is when I console.log the `profile` variable in my `googleStrategy`, I get the right user profile information for the account from Google. This means the authentication vis a vis Google is fine. However, this same account is NOT being provided to my `/auth/google/callback` endpoint in the `req.user` object at that location. It is an entirely different account (it is the first value from my database of Users, which is authenticated using local authentication).

How do I get the user object back to my Express callback endpoint that I supplied to Google in the developer console as the authorized redirect URI?

As a general question, what happens after the strategy calls `return done(null, existingUser);`? I have no callback in the `/auth/google` route after the `passport.authenticate()` middleware is called so what happens next?

I am using `"passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

My `let existingUser = await User.findOne({ 'google.id': profile.id });`
line was incorrect and was essentially returning no user. Mongoose does not complain and hence the strategy was just returning the first user from my database rather than the authenticated google user.